# Heroku connects to Redis localhost when calling Resque.enqueue in Rails 4 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, redis, resque

In Heroku when the Resque.enqueue command is run Heroku attempts to connect to redis via localhost. In the config/initializers/redis.rb the correct URL is set with $redis = Redis.new(url: ENV['REDIS_URL']) and $redis is instantiated without error. In the controller where the enqueue method is called $redis.inspect returns the correct value.

The error received is: Redis::CannotConnectError (Error connecting to Redis on localhost:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)):

**gemfile**

```
gem 'rails', '4.2.6' 
gem 'redis', "~> 4.1.0"
gem 'resque', "~> 1.27.3"
```

**config/initializers/redis.rb**

```
if Rails.env.production?
  $redis = Redis.new(url: ENV['REDIS_URL'])
  puts "$redis.inspect => #{$redis.inspect} "
end
```

**lib/tasks/resque.rake**

```
require "resque/tasks"
task "resque:setup" => :environment
```

**rakefile**
    task "resque:preload" => :environment

**procfile**

```
web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb
worker: env QUEUE=* bundle exec rake resque:work
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved and redis points to the correct server in Heroku.

In the config/initializers/redis.rb

Changed this:

```
  $redis = Redis.new(url: ENV['REDIS_URL'])
```

To this:

```
  $redis = Resque.redis = Redis.new(url: ENV['REDIS_URL'])
```